# how to check status of last ftp command

Tags: unix, ftp, dos

I have an automated dos script which gets files from Unix server using `ftp`. 
The directory structure follow a general pattern:

```
/path/to/dir/<changing_dir>/scripts
```

the code is like this: 
    cd /path/to/dir//scripts
    mget *.sh

So, I ftp and get all the scripts using `mget`. But there are some directories which do not have scripts directory inside them, so when I use this directory path in `cd` it fails and the mget gets the files from home directory instead of skipping.

Is it possible to check within `ftp` whether last command was successful or not?

Comment: Please follow the below ans and make it correct, If this really helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether command was successful or not then write the below lines in one file and save as .sh and then try like this:-

```
{
cd /path/to/dir//scripts mget *.sh && echo "Successful"
} || {
echo "fail"
}
```